# Highcharts blank chart with x and y axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to use highcharts creating a blank chart with no datas but x and y axis. 
How to do it?

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    yAxis: {        
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.value +' km';
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: []        
    }]

});
```

it returns

[image]

But I want to display y-axis with label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put data and hide the series after setting property

```
ignoreHiddenSeries : false
```

Here is [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/gzJRN/) If you hide the series Y-Axis will still be visible.

Comment: Thanks very much.It is usefull for my situation.

Answer (score 6):

You can put in your min/max values for the xAxis and yAxis and use null for all data.

[Forked](http://jsfiddle.net/duniyadnd/9SfAj/1/) from @ZaheerAhmed's response above as I figure it deserves a spot as an alternative solution without needing to hide the data after the fact.

i.e.

```
yAxis: {
   min: 1,
   max:
} ,
xAxis: {
   min: 1,
   max: 50
},
series: {
   data:[null,null]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a datetime x-axis, how do you configure the max and min values? I have tried to put an UTC value for an specific date, but no luck, chart still entire white

Comment: @estemendoza - do you have a jsfiddle for me to look at?

Comment: @estemendoza - HighChart uses the unix timestamp in milliseconds.

Comment: @JaredBroad - I tried to put min and max values in miliseconds but it didn't work

Comment: is it possible to remove the defalut names from the x axis as of now the default name are [series 1,series 2]

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it seems that highcharts has this functionality built in [yAxis.showEmpty](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.showEmpty)

Unfortunately, the fiddle listed in the documentation doesn't work, and there is a related open highcharts issue on the matter:

[no hide y axis](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/no-hide-y-axis-t25041/)

Answer (score 0):

Setting min and max for `xAxis` and `yAxis` is not a good solution! Because if the data is loaded later (When it's resolved), then you won't have auto calculated min and max. In [Highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max), it's said:

> If null, the max value is automatically calculated

So you should set min and max back to `null` when the data is loaded. But in my case setting it to null or even deleting the option, didn't result in automatic calculating (Seems strange).

What I did instead was setting [charts.showAxes](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.showAxes) to true! That's it. Take a look at [the demo provided by Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/showaxes-true/)

**Important:** You of course need to set series to something like this:

```
series: [
  {
    data: [null, null, null]
  },
  {
    data: [null, null, null]
  }
]
```

Note: Make sure [xAxis.showEmpty](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.showEmpty) and [yAxis.showEmpty](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.showEmpty) are set true (which is true by default).